# How do I use className twice in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

```
const Box = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    width:1024px;
`;

<Box>Test</Box>
```

-- Result

[image]

The result I want is below.

[image]

How do I use className twice in styled-components?

Comment: Can you include the code rather than screenshots?

Comment: My code is the first line. The final screenshot is not my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Styled components class names are auto-generated. There might be a hack to achieve this but it is not the intended way.

You can use the Box components in mutliple places by exporting it

```
export const Box = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    width:1024px;
;`
```

and reusing it in other components. This is is also the primary React paradigm. Reuse components whereever you can.